# Extract string from rules frozensets

Tags: python, apriori, market-basket-analysis, frozenset, mlxtend

With the following statement:

```
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1.2)
```

I get a data frame of rules in the format:

```
frozenset({'Co_Apples'})
```

But I need to extract a `Co_Apples` as a string.

How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks @ArnoldSchrijver

Comment: You seem to have a set of one element. You can convert it to a list, and take the first element: `list(rules)[0]`.

Comment: thanks @9000, the one item list is just an example but converting it to a list may be a good idea. I'll try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code to get a string from frozenset type columns and then cast the string to unicode.

```
rules["antecedents"] = rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0]).astype("unicode")
rules["consequents"] = rules["consequents"].apply(lambda x: list(x)[0]).astype("unicode")
```

Comment: In case you have item combinations (a frozenset with more than one value), using `list(x)[0]` will only show the first value.

You can use `', '.join( list(x) )` instead to separate the items with a comma.

`rules["antecedents"] = rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))).astype("unicode")`

Answer (score 10):

```
rules["antecedents"] = rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))).astype("unicode")
```

It is work for me.
Thanks [Frank Herfert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6390170/frank-herfert) save my day!